# Set UITextField as phone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-number

```
/*h file:*/

IBOutlet UITextField *Number;


/*m File:*/

[(Number) setText: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]];
```

Any idea why this is not working ?

The UIText Field Number just dosent change what so ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an empty or nil string as under that key.

Add this statement to check:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]);
```

Comment: Do you get the string you expected in the NSLog?

Comment: There is one more option that I see: you haven't connected the textfield in IB.

Comment: I'm not sure which one to explain, so I'll explain them both :D

1. The output to the console.
2. It means that you haven't dragged a line from that textfield to your object in interface builder (.xib file)

Comment: basically i can set text normally like: [(Number) setText:@"hi"]; but not with the number :S

Comment: Can you paste the console output of that NSLog?
Might help a bit

Comment: i have read that they have disabled this :/ sorry for your time mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Should read:

```
NSString * savedNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"];
if (savedNumber)
{
     [Number setText:savedNumber];
}
```